# Regarding Periods of Weierstrass $\wp$ function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, elliptic-functions

I am trying problems from Tom M Apostol Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in number theory and I am struck on this problem which is from Chapter - Elliptic Functions.

> Problem is - Prove that $\wp(u) = \wp (v) $ iff
>    $u-v$ or $u+v$ is a period of $\wp$ .

My attempt - assuming $u-v, u+v$ to be period of $\wp(z) $ , it is very easy to see $\wp (u)=\wp(v) $ .

But if I assume $\wp (u) =\wp (v) $ , then I get $\frac {u+v} {u^2 v^2}= \sum_\omega\neq 0 \frac { u+v - 2 \omega} {  ( u- \omega) ^2  × ( v-\omega ) ^2 } $  .

I don't know how to proceed after this. 
Can somebody please give some hint.

Comment: Use \wp for the Weierstrass $\wp$-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy part was already known to the OP, but since I wrote it let me keep it here: if $u-v = \omega_i$ with $\omega_i$ one of the periods, then it follows immediately that
$$
\wp(u) = \wp(\omega_i + v) = \wp(v),
$$
using that $\wp$ is periodic with period $\omega_i$. If we start from $u+v = \omega_i$ we use the fact that $\wp(-x) = \wp(x)$ to get rid of the extra minus sign.

The converse is slightly trickier: suppose $\wp(u) = \wp(v)$. Note that $\wp$ has a second order pole only, which implies it attains every complex number twice on the fundamental parallelogram. The evenness of $\wp$, i.e. $\wp(u) = \wp(-u)$, now implies that if $u,v$ are both in the fundamental parallelogram
$$
v = -u \text{ mod } \mathbb{L},
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
v+u = 0 \text{ mod } \mathbb{L}. 
$$
The only other possibility occurs when $u$ and $v$ are not in the same quadrant. The preceding implies that in that case $v=\pm u \text{ mod } \mathbb{L}$, so we find 
$$
v\pm u = 0 \text{ mod } \mathbb{L}. 
$$
This proves the asked.

Comment: this part is clear to me, I am asking for the converse.

Comment: Ah, yeah I see I was too quick reading the question. Let me think a bit about the conserve, which is definitely harder.

Comment: It is because $f(z)=\wp(z)-\wp(u)$ has two poles thus two zeros on the fundamental parallelogram $P$, and since it is even... (it has the same number of zeros/poles because $\int_{\partial P}f'/f(z)dz = 0$)

Comment: @Hrodelbert how can you say that as $\wp $ has second order pole only, so it will attain every complex number twice on fundamental Parellogram? Which result are you using?

Comment: @reuns I know the result which you mentioned in comment but how does it proves that either u+v or u-v will be its period?

Comment: @Hrodelbert everything in your answer is clear to me except the result which you use - $\wp$ has a second order pole implies that it will attain every value twice on period parallelogram. How did you deduced  this result?

Comment: $f(z)=\wp(z)-\wp(u)$ is even and has two zeros and one of them is $u$ thus the other one is $-u$ and it has no other on $P$, ie. $\wp(z)=\wp(u)$ iff $z\in \pm u +L$ @user686624

Comment: @reuns what you wrote is clear to me but how did your argument explained that $\wp$ will attain every complex number twice on period Parellogram ?

Comment: ... $\wp(z)-a$ has two zeros @user686624

Comment: @reuns yes got it now. Thanks a lot